# Make Object grow upwards in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, object

I was able to make an object grow to the right sucessfully, slowly, just the way I needed, but , how can I make it grow upwards?

This is what I was able to do (to make it grow to the right)

```
Private Sub growup()
If ActiveSheet.Shapes("image1").Width > 300 Then
Exit Sub
End If

For A = 1 To 200
With ActiveSheet.Shapes("image1")
.Width = .Width + 3
DoEvents

End With
Next A
end sub
```

Also, (just in case I need in the future) To the left?

Comment: What have you tried to make it grow "up" so far?

Comment: change the .Height

Comment: @QHarr - Changing just the height will make it "grow down". You'd need to increase the `.Top` and `.Height` simultaneously.

Answer (score 1):

Use the other available properties of

```
.Height
.Top
```

There is also

.Left   '<==For indent

As per @Comintern's point you do need to adjust  `.Top` and `.Height` together!

See full property list of shape object here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/shape-object-excel